# Is it possible to create Time elapsed video from Cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudinary, cloud-storage

Is there any cloud system which provides image storing and also manipulates when retrieving? For example, I've 7 images on my storage and I want to build a video from this, I don't know whether it is possible or not. please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) you can generate an animated GIF of multiple images and then convert this GIF to either MP4 or WebM. See -

http://cloudinary.com/blog/cloud_based_animated_gif_generation
http://cloudinary.com/blog/reduce_size_of_animated_gifs_automatically_convert_to_webm_and_mp4

Comment: Is there any way to create video from existing GIF on cloudinary. because in current flow we need to upload the gif file first using below reference :
http://cloudinary.com/blog/reduce_size_of_animated_gifs_automatically_convert_to_webm_and_mp4

Comment: Indeed, Cloudinary needs the file to be stored on your account first in order to create transformed versions of it. You can use the [remote fetching mechanism](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images) and manipulate the GIF on-the-fly.